# Buscar encontrar y reemplazar dentro de string en php

Tags: php

Amigos buen día. hoy vengo con otra duda, tengo un string de la siguiente forma.

```
{"idc100":"1",
"creado_por":"superadmin",
"asignado":"Yhowan Ramirez",
"ips":"["melgar","corondo"]",
"numero":"200116001232201602345",
"devolucion":"["porque si","porque no"]"}
```

y necesito encontrar estos valores que están dentro de `[]` ejemplo `["melgar","corondo"]` y formatearlo para que quede simplemente asi: `melgar - corondo`, con el fin de que el `string` quede así:

```
{"idc100":"1",
 "creado_por":"superadmin",
 "asignado":"Yhowan Ramirez",
 "ips":" melgar - corondo",
 "numero":"200116001232201602345",
 "devolucion":"porque si - porque no"}
```

Alguna manito se les agradece, gracias!!

Comment: ¿De dónde viene ese string, ¿acaso es una consulta a tu base de datos?

Answer (score 3):

Se te ha pasado la comillas dobles al lado de los corchetes "[]" esto causa un error de sintaxis.

El formato correcto seria:

```
{"idc100":"1",
"creado_por":"superadmin",
"asignado":"Yhowan Ramirez",
"ips":["melgar","corondo"],
"numero":"200116001232201602345",
"devolucion":["porque si","porque no"]}
```

Ya con esto el siguiente script podría hacer lo que necesitas:

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');

$json = '{"idc100":"1",
"creado_por":"superadmin",
"asignado":"Yhowan Ramirez",
"ips":["melgar","corondo"],
"numero":"200116001232201602345",
"devolucion":["porque si","porque no"]}';

$data_array = json_decode($json, true);

$data_array["ips"] = implode( ' - ', $data_array["ips"] );
$data_array["devolucion"] = implode( ' - ', $data_array["devolucion"] );

$json = json_encode($data_array);

echo $json;
```